# flow type alert redux-saga when call([context, fnName], ...args) is used

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, redux-saga

I have user `call([context, fnName], ...args)` based in the `redux-saga` document and there is the alert from flow type. My code is look like below:

```
yield call([middlewareSvc, 'getRequest'], 'auth/validate', idTokenInfo, {})
```

So, how can we prevent this alert from flowtype

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this myself, and have instead used `yield call([middlewareSvc, middlewareSvc.getRequest], ...)` (using your example)

Comment: just interesting: what exact warning message looks like?